# Django: delete an item from a table but keep a record of deleted item

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm making an inventory app for tools in my workshop. I created a view that manages the tools in toolboxes and to whom the boxes are assigned to, I am able to create tools in the toolbox using the **CreateView** class, but i don't know how to remove the tool from the box.

(Lets say that one of the tools broke and we would have to replace it, I want to keep a record of that transaction,  what cart it was in and the reason for discarding the item. Also I want to check if it was a non-disposable item or if was a consumable item(**if the item broke by bad use   or if the item weared down to an unusable state**)).

How can I go about this issue?

models for creating the tool cart(carrito)

```
=========================================================================== #
#   MODELO PARA CREAR CARRITOS
# =========================================================================== #


class Carritos(models.Model):
    no_carrito = models.CharField(max_length=3, unique=True)
    empleado = models.OneToOneField(Empleados, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # empleado = models.ManyToManyField(Empleados,  through='Transaccion')
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, through='Transaccion', related_name='carritos')
    f_creacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    f_actualizacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    activo = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('inventario:carrito')#, kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Carritos"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.no_carrito



class Transaccion(models.Model):

    carrito = models.ForeignKey(Carritos, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='items_carrito')
    Herramienta = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='items_carrito')
    cantidad = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('inventario:carrito')#, kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**views.py**

```
# =========================================================================== #
#   LOGICA PARA CREAR CARRITOS
# =========================================================================== #
# ===================> Logica relacinado con Cortadores <=====================#

def create_carrito(request):
    template_name = 'inventario/carrito/createcarrito.html'
    model  = Carritos

    carritos = Carritos.objects.all()
    if carritos:
        return render(request, template_name, {'carritos':carritos})

    else:
        return render(request,template_name)


class CarritoCreate(CreateView):
    model = Carritos
    fields = [
        'no_carrito',
        'empleado',
        'activo',
    ]

class ItemCreate(CreateView):
    model = Transaccion
    fields = [
        'carrito',
        'Herramienta',
        'cantidad',
    ]


def detalle_carrito(request, pk):
    model = Carritos, Transaccion
    template_name = 'inventario/carrito/detalles_carrito.html'

    carritos = Carritos.objects.all().filter(pk=pk)
    trans =Transaccion.objects.filter(carrito=pk)

    return render(request,template_name, {'carrito':carritos, 'trans':trans} )


class CarritoUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Carritos

    fields = [
        'no_carrito',
        'empleado',
        'activo',
    ]
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
```

Comment: Maybe you can make them `inactive` ? instead of deleting

Comment: Ok I could, but how can i append all those other fields I want to have like the reason it broke and if it was a non-disposable or a consumable item ?

Comment: Add those as fields in model ? charField for reason and choices for type ?

Comment: would that bee in  what table  Items , Carritos or Transaccion?

Comment: Whichever refers to `Item` model

Answer (score 0):

add one filed like this,in Carritos(it has parent relation to  Transaccion)

class Carritos(models.Model):

```
is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

Carritos.objects.filter(is_deleted=True) # gives all records which marked as deleted
Carritos.objects.filter(is_deleted=False) # gives all records which marked as not deleted
```

Comment: Thanks!, would it  mark my ** Carrito ** as disable? if i where to search for Carritos that are active ? what I'm tying to do is disable juts the item in a  carrito wil  this work ?

Comment: means disabling carrito model for particular user

Comment: Ok. Well thats the issue ! I don't want to disable the Carrito for that user. Lets put it this way. I will always have a fixed number of carritos  with the same tools  per Carrito. What I'm attempting to do is: If  Carlos carrito's plyers got damaged  I want to have that on record. Eventualy I would have to drop and replace the plyers in Carlos carrito  but the carrito wont ever be disabled